# Which packages are required to install Oracle 11.2.0.3 on Solaris 11?

Tags: oracle, installation

Where can I find information on which packages are required to install Oracle 11.2.0.3 on Solaris 11? The documentation only mentions Solaris 10. I tracked down the [packages required for Solaris 10](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24349/toc.htm#CHDHFGBJ), and most of them are either included in the GA release of Solaris 11 or obsoleted.

There are however a couple of packages that are missing from the base install of Solaris 11:

- `SUNWarc` (renamed to):

  - `consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation` (installed)
  - `developer/library/lint` **(missing)**
- `SUNWhea` (renamed to):

  - `consolidation/osnet/osnet-incorporation` (installed)
  - `system/header` **(misising)**

So it looks like `developer/library/lint` and `system/header` are packages from required for Solaris 10 that are missing from the Solaris 11 base install.

The installer however doesn't seem to be looking for any packages whatsoever. Although it does check the kernel version (5.11) Does that mean all the packages needed are bundled in Solaris 11 and  it's safe to install the database?

Answer (score 2):

The Solaris 11 (11.2) install uses groups of packages called:
solaris-desktop
solaris-large-server
solaris-small-server
solaris-minimal-server
The group is defined in a install manifest during AI install
Oracle also provides a x86 (64bit) desktop install iso
A SPARC or x86 Text server install
See the install documentation for  the list of files if you really want it.
Solaris no longer uses SVR4 packages to install OS packages, it now uses IPS packages.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/index.html